# JSON schema: conditional dependency

Tags: json, jsonschema

I can't seem to figure out how to achieve something in JSON schema. Let's say I have two fields: `status` and `quote`.

Conditional dependencies are as follow:

- IF `status` is `["Y", "N"]`, THEN `quote` is **required**
- IF `status` is anything else from enum, THEN `quote` is **not required**
- IF `status` is not present in JSON, THEN `quote` can be anything

I am trying to achieve this behaviour with the following schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "quote": {
      "type": "string",
    },

    "status": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["Y", "N", "M", "A", "S"]
    }
  },
  
  "oneOf": [
      {
        "properties": {
          "status": {"enum": ["Y", "N"]}
        },
        "required": [
          "quote"
        ]
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "status": {"enum": ["Y", "N", "M", "A", "S"]}
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

The first two conditions work as expected, but whenever the `status` field is left out from the JSON, the validation fails. And the wanted behaviour is that I can have a field `quote` to be whatever whenever `status` field is not there.

How can I achieve this?

### UPDATE

So I managed to achieve what I asked initially, however, I now have the additional requirement. That is, I have an additional field `author` that is required whenever `status` is `["M", "A"]` and otherwise it's just optional. If `status` is not present, both `quote` and `author` can be anything. I tried that like follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "quote": { "type": "string" },
    "author": { "type": "string" },
    "status": { "enum": ["Y", "N", "M", "A", "S"] }
  },
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/y-or-n-requires-quote" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/m-or-a-requires-author" }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "y-or-n-requires-quote": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/status-is-y-or-n" } },
        { "required": ["quote"] }
      ]
    },
    "m-or-a-requires-author": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/status-is-m-or-a" } },
        { "required": ["author"] }
      ]
    },
    
    "status-is-y-or-n": {
      "properties": {
        "status": { "enum": ["Y", "N"] }
      }
    },
    
    "status-is-m-or-a": {
      "properties": {
        "status": { "enum": ["M", "A"] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, using this schema doesn't work for JSON where `status` is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a boolean logic concept called implication (!A or B).  It's a way of expressing an if-then constraint.  In this case, what we want to express is: either status is not "Y"/"N" or quote is required.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "quote": { "type": "string" },
    "status": { "enum": ["Y", "N", "M", "A", "S"] }
  },
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/y-or-n-requires-quote" }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "y-or-n-requires-quote": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/status-is-y-or-n" } },
        { "required": ["quote"] }
      ]
    },
    "status-is-y-or-n": {
      "properties": {
        "status": { "enum": ["Y", "N"] }
      },
      "required": ["status"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, that worked. However, what if I need additionally if status is ["M" or "A"], then "author" property is required? And if status is not "M" or "A" then "author" is optional. So that in addition to the "quote" part that works in this version. Could you please update your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure when I'll have a chance to update the answer, but this technique will work for any number of implications you need. Just definite another implication and add it to the `allOf`.

Comment: Please look at my update. I tried something like you say, but it doesn't work the way I tried it. It works when the "status" is present, but whenever "status" is not there, validation fails. And I want to be able to have just the "author" field or just the "quote" field. (It works when both "author" and "quote" are present)

Comment: @wesleyy The "status-is-y-or-n" definition should have required the "status" property.  I've updated my answer.  With that, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Note that draft-07 adds "if"/"then"/"else" keywords to make conditionals easier:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-00#section-6.6

If your tools don't support draft-07 please consider filing a feature request to get them to update :-)